# How to Write a Simple iPad App/Script to Randomly Select Students and Track Absences

Tags: ipad

I am a teacher using an iPad in the classroom. I want to create a simple application or script that can randomly select students' names to answer questions. However, I also need the ability to mark certain students as absent, so their names are not called again during that class session.

I am comfortable with programming, but I would prefer not to develop a full-fledged native iOS app for this specific task. Is there a simple way to create a Graphical User Interface (GUI) application or script that can run on an iPad and fulfill the following requirements:

1. Randomly select a student's name from a list.
2. Allow me to mark students as absent, so their names are not called again during that class.

I suppose I can always write a web App and host it somewhere, but then I will have rely on internet connection. I am looking for an offline solution.

Comment: We aren’t a script writing service. Where we can assist is where are you get stuck on a very specific problem or issue but we can’t get your script going from scratch. Can you narrow it down to a specific problem that you’re encountering?

Comment: @Allan I am just asking for advice which programming language or framework I should use. I will figure out the details myself. I don't have a MacBook, so that puts some limitation on my options.

Comment: How exactly do you plan on coding this, then (with no laptop/desktop)?   You need to work in a language you’re familiar with.   Finally, you asked *How to…* not *what should I use*, but that too is likely to be off topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My usual method for randomizing is to list the items/names in a column of a LibreOffice spreadsheet and put `=rand()` in another column.  Title the columns in the top row and turn on the "filters".  Each time you "sort ascending" on the random column, the list gets shuffled into a new sequence.  If you want to skip certain items, just clear the `=rand()` cell for that student.  That causes them to always sort to the bottom of the list.  After class, use "fill down" to put the formula back in those cells.

However, for calling on students, an easier way (in my opinion) is just put each student's name on a popsicle stick, put all the sticks in a cup/jar/pocket, and pull one out each time.

Comment: Technology is a great thing, but by the time you expend time/effort/money into a technology solution, something that works NOW is often best.